# \square macro in xymtex

Tags: xymtex

Consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtex}
%\usepackage[chemist]{chemtimes}
\begin{document}

\tetrahedral{0==A;1==B;2==C;3==D;4==E}

\end{document}
```

It's very simple and it pdf-compiles on my linux box (ubuntu 10.04, texlive 2009)

Now consider this similar code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtex}
%\usepackage[chemist]{chemtimes}
%\usepackage{aliphat}
\begin{document}

\square{0==A;1==B;2==C;3==D;4==E}

\end{document}
```

On pdf and dvi compiling this last code I get the following error

> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
>
> --- TeX said --- l.6 \square
>              {0==A;1==B;2==C;3==D;4==E}
>   --- HELP --- TeX encountered an unknown command name. .....

Uncommenting the two \usepackage lines  do not solve the problem.

Any idea ??

Comment: The command `\square` has been replaced by `\squareplanar` to avoid conflicts. Somehow this didn't get into the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aliphat.sty` subpackage is always loaded, so there's no need to call it explicitly.

The `\square` macro has been disabled and substituted by `\squareplanar` in order to avoid conflicts with math packages that use the `\square` macro.

Here's an extract from `aliphat.dtx`:

```
3191 % The command |\square| is renamed to be |\squareplanar|. The code is entirely replaced. 
3192 %
3193 % \changes{v4.05}{2009/11/08}{Bug fix: \cs{square} to \cs{squareplanar}}
```

For some reason, the change didn't make its way into the documentation.